# Searching for Records in Berkeley DB JE

Tags: search, berkeley-db, berkeley-db-je

For example, suppose you have database records that use the following Strings as keys:

```
Alabama
Alaska
Arizona
```

Providing a key of Al moves the cursor to the first key (Alabama),

Now, I think the returned result should be UNFOUNDED if provided the search key by "Al". What should I do to ensure that the key is completely matched.

Comment: Can you include a code sample please, so we can see what is it you're trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

I thought about it and if you want an exact match, it's easier to use the `get()` methods of your indices.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you're making the call to get the key. Some source code would help clarify your question. You can also get quicker answers to these types of questions in the Berkeley DB Java Edition [forum](http://bit.ly/e1AYFi) on OTN.